# Why do the heap.Pop wields with reversed array?

Tags: arrays, go, heap

I am working with IntHeap exmaple from [Package Heap](https://golang.org/pkg/container/heap/). Every thing looks very simple for a minHEAP. Take a Look how to get the minimum value: we just require the `(*h)[0]` value. And as like as in the description of heap the root node returns minimum value

```
fmt.Printf("minimum: %d\n", (*h)[0]) // It will returns 1
```

Strange things starts at the `Pop()` method. In this case minimum value is stored at the end of the array.  `x := old[n-1]`. But 2 lines above I get same minimum value from by the index 0.

Hm... it's very interesting. How it happens that Go represent reversed array for a Pop method?
This is curious, and minstical and uncommon, to imagine different order of the array in different methods.

I added two lines to the example, and yes, Go pass reversed array into the Pop method:

```
fmt.Println("In Pop",*h) // In Pop [2 3 5 1]
fmt.Println("In Main",*h) // In Main [1 2 5 3]
```

- Why do we need to reverse array each time?
- Does it requres O(n) on every Pop call?

Here is a full example with two changes:

```
// This example demonstrates an integer heap built using the heap interface.
package main

import (
    "container/heap"
    "fmt"
)

// An IntHeap is a min-heap of ints.
type IntHeap []int

func (h IntHeap) Len() int           { return len(h) }
func (h IntHeap) Less(i, j int) bool { return h[i] < h[j] }
func (h IntHeap) Swap(i, j int)      { h[i], h[j] = h[j], h[i] }

func (h *IntHeap) Push(x interface{}) {
    // Push and Pop use pointer receivers because they modify the slice's length,
    // not just its contents.
    *h = append(*h, x.(int))
}

func (h *IntHeap) Pop() interface{} {
    fmt.Println("In Pop",*h) // In Pop [2 3 5 1]
    old := *h
    n := len(old)
    x := old[n-1]
    *h = old[0 : n-1]
    return x
}

// This example inserts several ints into an IntHeap, checks the minimum,
// and removes them in order of priority.
func main() {
    h := &IntHeap{2, 1, 5}
    heap.Init(h)
    heap.Push(h, 3)
    fmt.Printf("minimum: %d\n", (*h)[0])
    fmt.Println("In Main",*h) // In Main [1 2 5 3]
    for h.Len() > 0 {
        fmt.Printf("%d ", heap.Pop(h))
    }
}
```

and the output

```
minimum: 1
In Main [1 2 5 3]
In Pop [2 3 5 1]
1 In Pop [3 5 2]
2 In Pop [5 3]
3 In Pop [5]
5
```

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/container/heap/#Pop `Pop removes and returns the minimum element (according to Less) from the heap. The complexity is O(log n) where n = h.Len().` its not `reversing order`, it is re balancing the tree, that it appears reversed is just a consequence of the representation of the tree using a slice. i cannot find where you read that `(*h)[0]` would give the root node.

Comment: What does 'wields' mean in your title?

Comment: Don't edit languages into the title of your question. Use tags for that.

Comment: @Flimzy: Your edits are being discussed in these meta questions: [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390349/), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389839)

Comment: @Cerbrus: Thanks for the heads-up. Looks like it's been adequately discussed already. Unless you think my input is needed, I'm going to leave it alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you initialize a heap from a slice using `Init`, it establishes heap invariants by rearranging the slice. This operation is `O(n)` and only happens once, on init, not on every pop!

Then, when you `Pop`, each `Pop` takes only `O(log n)`. Performing the init is essential to ensure we could pop in `O(log n)`.

Read more about heaps [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)). The [article on Heapsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) has pseudocode for the *heapify* operation which is performed by `heap.Init`)

---

What `Pop` does is not reversing. It:

1. Swaps the minimal element (which is at `[0]`) with the last element in the underlying slice. Now the minimal element is at the very end, and the element `[0]` is in the "wrong" place in the heap.
2. Uses the `down` primitive to move the new element `[0]` to its right place in the heap. This reshuffles some of the heap's elements - but it's not a reversion.
3. Removes and returns element `[n-1]`, which from step 1 is the original minimal element.

Comment: Most interesting thing is that: when I request slice by a pointer outside the Pop it have one order, when I work with the same slice slice by the same pointer from the Pop function it have reversed order. Does it means that on each Pop call array revered twice?

Comment: The question is more about technique using under the hood of reversing a slice under the pointer before Pop, and after the Pop. To deliver normal order HeapSlice outside the Pop, and reversed inside the Pop. How do this revesing.... 
I GOT IT :)  It is not reversing. It's  HEAP algorithm.

Comment: Added some details to the answer of what Pop actually does

Comment: Eli,  I added almost the same answer 20 minutes ago below yours. Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

This is not reversing. It's an algorithm of removing minimum element from a MinHeap.

1. Swap root element with last element.
2. Remove lest element
3. Heapify the structure.

In current case package delegate to developer step #2. And implementing step #1 and step #3 for all Heap except the last element.

https://youtu.be/WCm3TqScBM8?t=391